# Matching words that may contain 1-2 digits

Tags: regex

I use the following regex for matching words with a length of 4 that has 1 number and 3 capital letters:

```
\b(?=[A-Z]*\d[A-Z]*\b)[A-Z\d]{4}\b
```

What I would like to know is how I need to modify the expression to filter out words with a length of 10, that contains 0-2 numbers.

```
\b(?=[A-Z]*\d[A-Z]*\b)[A-Z\d]{10}\b
```

This will work for 1 number occurence, but how do i extend it to filter 0 and 2 numbers as well?

Sample: http://regexr.com?32u40

Comment: Are the numbers always going to be adjacent? If that is the case, this should work: `\b(?=[A-Z]*\d{0,2}[A-Z]*\b)[A-Z\d]{10}\b`

Comment: @Asad Yes, sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the length check into the lookahead:

```
\b(?=[A-Z\d]{10}\b)(?:[A-Z]*\d){0,2}[A-Z]*\b
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b           # Start at a word boundary
(?=          # Assert that...
 [A-Z\d]{10} # 10 A-Z/digits follow
 \b          # until the next word boundary.
)            # (End of lookahead)
(?:          # Match...
 [A-Z]*      # Any number of ASCII uppercase letters
 \d          # and exactly one digit
){0,2}       # repeat 0, 1 or 2 times.
[A-Z]*       # Match any number of letters
\b           # until the next word boundary.
```

Comment: Thumbs up.  Looks correct, but still returns a positive match with value of "" where the lookahead matches, but where the value contains too many numbers.  Add a filter to remove those: `x.match(/\b(?=[A-Z\d]{10})(?:[A-Z]*\d){0,2}[A-Z]*\b/g).filter(function(y){return y.length == 10});`

Comment: @TheSmose: Thanks; I had misread the question and thought there should be 10 characters or more. I've corrected the regex - one additional word boundary is enough, no need for a filter.